# Need help on Codeigniter to solve an error on Controller and Model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

**Model/blogmodel.php:**

```
class Blogmodel extends CI_Model {
    public function get_recent_post($num){
        $query = $this->db->get('wdr_blog_post', $num);
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**Controller/blog.php:**

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->load->model('blogmodel');
        $posts = $this->Blogmodel->get_recent_post(5);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Blog::$Blogmodel

Filename: controllers/blog.php

Line Number: 7

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_recent_post() on a non-object in G:\server\htdocs\xyz\app\controllers\blog.php on line 7

Comment: $this->blogmodel should be lowercase!

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing...

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->Blogmodel = $this->load->model('blogmodel');
        $posts = $this->Blogmodel->get_recent_post(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. First error solved. But still showing **"Fatal error: Call to a member function get_recent_post() on a non-object in G:\server\htdocs\xyz\app\controllers\blog.php on line 7"**